# getting callback error even though "I think" I set it up as a function

Tags: node.js, callback

I have this function:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    getEventLog.getId(id, uuid, function(err, id, code, callback){ 
      getEventLog.getDuration(id, uuid, function(err, duration, callback){
          jobRunDbService.update(jobRun, function(data, error){
            if (error) {
              ...
            }
            callback(err, jobRun.id); 
          })
        });
      });     
  });
```

It throws the following error:

> /Users/paulcarron/git/integration-test-runner/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> TypeError: callback is not a function
>       at modules/jobRunningService.js:77:15

Line 77 is the `callback(err, jobRun.id);`

To the best of my knowledge the callback should work but I've obviously got something wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not print out the type of `callback` before the failing line (`typeof(callback)`)? Then, perhaps output its value.

Comment: Thanks @jpaugh. A good starting point. I printed to console. Its just a number(638 the last time I ran it). The correct number is getting printed but the callback still errors.

Comment: If the callback is a number, then it is definitely *not* correct.

Comment: Ah OK. Why is that and can I simply cast to string?(Apologies if terminology is wrong. I'm new to Node.js).

Comment: I thought you wanted callback to be a function, not a string?

Comment: I don't use Node myself. I recommend taking out anything unrelated to the actual problem, though; this makes it easier for others (and yourself) to scan for the error.

Comment: ...especially, logging and whatnot. Check out [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll clean it up.

Regarding the return as function/string. I'm not entirely sure. As I say, I'm new to this. Can I return a number?

Comment: You can return whatever you want, but first `callback` has to be a function. You can't invoke a number or a string.